# I have persistent SSH session running. How do I start another one with disabled ControlMaster?

Tags: ssh

I have persistent SSH session running.

How do I start another one with disabled ControlMaster?

I tried passing `ControlMaster=no` as option to `ssh` but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Both `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath` options should be disabled if you have them enabled by default in your `~/.ssh/config` file.

So use the following command to access your host:

```
ssh -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none your-server-hostname
```